# Protect against DOS with iptables

Tags: iptables, denial-of-service

Is there any way to protect against dos by analysing how much connection in a port have been done by an ip and not limit the traffic overall?

For instance, let's say I don't want an ip to do more than 10 http requests per 10seconds, how I can do that? Knowing that there will be no ban if there's 100 requests in 10 seconds and if each requests have a different IP (protection only for DOS and not DDOS).

Answer (score 0):

check out https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page. It is a software rate limiter that uses ip tables

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to do such with this.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 10/second --limit-burst 12 -j ACCEPT
```

Anyway enable syncookies too.
Add this line to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
```

Then run sysctl -p or reboot to apply.

Comment: I tried the first rule but I still can make 1000 requests with a concurrency of 100 in 3 second and with ab command line.

Comment: I edited my answer following your comment, you where right. Try this and let us know.

Comment: it didn't work for my container but then I said to myself it may be related to the fact that my port is exposed by docker. So I installed apache2 (or httpd) and it did work. So Maybe I need to apply it for `FORWARD` and not `INPUT`

Comment: Just place a log rule and take a look at where packets for this connection are going through netfilter.

Comment: can you give me the commands to launch for logging?